# MVC: Html.Serialize vs Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently implementing a wizard for making an order, it consists out of a few steps, but this differs per product.

I have to save state between steps, so the user can jump back and forth and make adjustments.

To do this, and after some browsing, it seems there are two ways to do this:

- Have a main ViewModel with child-models for each Step, then Html.Serialize the models in your page
- Just store the whole object in Session

I am wondering why I would choose either method. The first one has been introduced in MVC2 in 2009, and that's also about as old as all posts regarding Html.Serialize date back, so I'm wondering if its still an accepted way. Especially given it has a lot away from ViewState, which was far from secure in ASP.NET.

Session seems the most logical choice after that, but I wonder what the downsides are. Will my session be lost if the app-pool decides to recycle? Session is server-side right?

Thanks!

Little side-note: Not interested in doing it with Javascript at this point, I'd like to keep this serverside. Hence I didn't list it as a third option.

Comment: If you are using InProc Sessions (the default), then yes, Session will get lost when the app-pool recycles.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is all about embracing the stateless nature of the web, so why use session? Keep the data in input/hidden variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Session has a limited lifetime and won't work properly if the user has multiple tabs opened on your wizard.

Keeping data in hidden fields is cleaner as it is truely stateless unless it's too big or you have to keep it server side for security reason.

I advice you to try with hidden fields and switch to session only if there is an issue.